# Rails paperclip how to create multiple image uploads and paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a image upload for my company model, but it is only for 1 image.
Now I want the photo model to handle two different images.

My company model:

```
class Virksomhed < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :photo, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

My Photo model:

```
require 'open-uri'

    class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :virksomhed
      attr_accessor :image_url

      has_attached_file :image,
              :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                      :url  => "/images/:style/:id/:basename.:extension",
                      :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"

    before_validation :download_remote_image, :if => :image_url_provided?

    private

      def image_url_provided?
        !self.image_url.blank?
      end

      def download_remote_image
        self.image = do_download_remote_image
        self.image_remote_url = image_url
      end

      def do_download_remote_image
        io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
        def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
        io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
      rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
      end

    end
```

What should I do?

1. Create a new image model like "Photo2 model" and copy and paste the code from the photo model?

or change the assocation so that company has many photos. Then I just don´t know how I should keep track of the 2 different images and how the routing should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Virksomhed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo1, :class_name => "Photo", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :photo2, :class_name => "Photo", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Instead of photo1 and photo2 you can use names that are more descriptive depending on what they are used for. I just used photo1 and photo2 as examples.